# Is there a specific time to use c++11 over c++17

Tags: c++11

Let's say I want to create a modern c++ application. I have zero legacy code that requires backward compatibility with c++98/03. Is there a reason to choose c++11 or c++14 over c++17?

From researching this, there don't appear to be any breaking changes between c++11 and c++17. It looks like c++17 is c++11 with more and more features. I realize that there are more compilers that support c++11 features than all the new c++17 changes.

So Compiler support is a consideration because it can affect portability. Also c++17 is not officially released, but at some point it will be.

What are the criteria I should evaluate in order to choose between C++11 and C++17? I'm looking for non-opinion based reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: "No breaking changes" is to be taken with caution. One thing that differs between C++11 and 14 is `constexpr` functions not being `const`, so they're different overloads. C++17 removes `operator++` from `bool` as well as a couple of other things (exception specifications, `register`, trigraphs, a couple of library funcs). Expression order of evaluation was changed, as were braced-init deduction rules.... all in all it's not just the same, there _are_ breaking changes.

Comment: some C++17 features can be implemented in a non-standard way as the standard is not released yet (same about some C++14 features). also there're some minor backward-incompatible changes, e.g. changes to `std::allocator` from the top of my head, though on practice this shouldn't be a big deal

Comment: @Damon Your other examples are correct but AFAIK order of evaluation was only tightened, not widened. In other words every evaluation order in 17 was valid before 17 as well. So the only way this can break your code is if it was UB/unspecified to start.

Comment: I would suggest that you look at what libraries you need to use for your project, and what versions of the standard they support. And also of course what platforms / compilers you need to target. I think oftentimes it's not specific language features that you desperately want for your code, but the ability to use a specific library that won't compile if you don't have e.g. generic lambdas. OTOH if a library uses features that MSVC doesn't support, you may end up targetting older MSVC and older libraries instead, or deciding to skip MSVC

Comment: If the question were "What are the criteria I should evaluate when choosing between C++11, and C++17?" this question would not be opinion based. Opinion is how one evaluate each criteria and the weight associated to each criteria. The list of criteria is not based on an opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like this is going to get closed as vague, opinion based, but what the heck. Keep in mind that 14 is between 11 and 17 as well, and much more widely supported. There's basically no reason to use 11 over 14 for a new codebase now, that I can think of. For 17, the problem is like you said, compiler support. If you need to target windows, MSVC is still missing tons of 17 support: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B17_features.

In order to write cross platform, 17 code right now, you almost certainly need some heavy duty continuous integration that will build and run your code on at least 2 if not 3 compilers every time you push.

If you are not targeting windows, or even if you can just commit to a single compiler, I don't see any reason not to use 17. (by that I mean: if you are only targeting MSVC, it's 17 support is partway there but there's little downside to using whats available, if something isn't supported it won't build. It's when you support different compilers that support different things, and you aren't building them all locally that it becomes a nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

In general, that means independently from C++, when they are no restriction due to legacy stuff, it is recommended to use the most recent version of a system or language.

Reasons to go a version step back may be

- tool support for this version is unsufficient (this may differ from project to project)
- tools are known to be buggy
- version spec is not completed
- only judge about you really get, not what other promise for the future.

This list may be incomplete